# ListView.View = View.LargerIcons;?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a WinForms .Net 2.o app with a `ListView` in it and i'm trying to show some thumbnails. I set the `listView.View`-property to `View.LargeIcon`, but that's not big enough. I would like to have thumbnails about 250x180. Is this possible? And if, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, edit the ImageList you use for the ListView.LargeImageList property.  Set its ImageSize to 250x180.